# (SOLVED) Power BI, Page level filter not working with many to one relation

Tags: powerbi

EDIT: Solution found.

Turns out the relations were set to `Cross filter direction: Single` on all relations (and the one from `Month table.Month` to `A.Month` was not set to active).

Setting `Cross filter direction: Both` fixed the problem.

---

I have four tables `A`, `B`, `Month table` and `Quarter table`

`A` has a column `A.Month`, and many other columns with irrelevant data

`B` has a column `B.Quarter`, and many other columns with irrelevant data

`Month table` has columns `Month table.Month` and `Month table.Quarter`

`Quarter table` has a column `Quarter table.Quarter`

---

One to many relations are shown as this: `"<"`

`Quarter table.Quarter < Month table.Quarter` as there are multiple (3) months in one quarter

`Month table.Month < A.Month` as there are several rows of data for each month

`Quarter table.Quarter < B.Quarter` as there are several rows of data for each quarter

---

Here is a visualisation of the relations

[image]

---

On my dashboard, I have a visual for `A`, and a visual for `B`

What I'm trying to do is to apply a page level filter with `Month table.Month`, thinking that therefore, `A` should only show data for whatever month/months are selected in the filter, and `B` should show the data for the corresponding quarter/quarters.

---

- Filter to January

  Expectation:

  - `A` shows data for January
  - `B` shows data for Q1

  Reality:

  - `A` shows data for all months
  - `B` shows data for all quarters
- Switch page level filter from `Month table.Month` to `Quarter table.Quarter` and set filter to Q1

  Expectation:

  - `A` shows data for January, February and Mars
  - `B` shows data for Q1

  Reality:

  - `A` shows data for all months
  - `B` shows data for Q1

---

What am I missing?

Comment: It is better to write an answer and mark it as correct if you solved it by yourself.

Comment: I tried to do that initially when I posted this but it wouldn't let me. Now I tried to undelete my old comment and it now suddenly let me mark my own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer.

Turns out the relations were set to `Cross filter direction: Single` on all relations (and the one from `Month table.Month` to `A.Month` was not set to active).

Setting `Cross filter direction: Both` fixed the problem.